# How to Invert Logo .PNG and Social icon on only one page on Squarespace Henson Template?

Tags: css

I just turned one page of my squarespace in black, I would like to know if it's possible to **invert my logo .PNG and Social Icon in white ?**

Here is the link of the page if you want to see :
https://www.novmbrcreative.com/novmbrstudio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be accomplished via the following CSS. It uses the collection ID, then targets the logo and the social icons with the CSS 'invert' filter:

```
#collection-5e827250f835166c09c3dcbe .site-branding, #collection-5e827250f835166c09c3dcbe .header-social-icons-right {
  -webkit-filter: invert(1);
  filter: invert(1);
}
```